# Do HP printers have batteries?

Tags: printer, battery, troubleshooting, network-printer

I have an HP p1606dn printer which keeps forgetting his LAN configuration and going back to factory settings.

So, I wonder if HP printers, (or maybe printers in general), have a battery, which could be dead, and needs replacement (like it happens with motherboard batteries).

I have been googling it, and got not a hint.

Comment: Try to [Restore factory settings](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02009697).

Comment: My mother has a very new Lexmark printer which always asks for the date upon turning it on. She doesn't like to leave devices on standby so she always unplugs the mains cable. The printer basically expects to always be connected to the power socket, and just be put in standby, which is how it remembers its settings. The same can be the case for your HP printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most printers do not have batteries. Instead, settings are stored in NVRAM, which does not require battery backup.

In the case of the LaserJet Pro P1600, the [Service Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/447419/Hp-Laserjet-Pro-P1600.html) does not mention the word "battery". Hence it seems this printer follows the general rule: no battery.

As for your problem, if @harrymc's suggestion of resetting the printer to factory defaults does not fix it, you may want to contact HP for a new network card.